# How to use jaxb_commons plugins from maven

Tags: plugins, maven-2, jaxb, jaxb2-basics

I'm trying to use a jaxb plugin to insert a interface into a choice element generating the classes from maven. The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to do so from maven, the repository isn't clear from the documentation and the only example (bellow) doesn't work, it seems to ignore the plugin (maven reports no error about not finding it) or the plugin doesn't have all the adds-ons currently listed in the project documentation:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <generatePackage>br.com.wonder.nfe.xml</generatePackage>
        <args>
            <arg>-Xifins</arg>
        </args>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>basic</artifactId>
                <version>0.4.1.5</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I have these in the root pom:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>maven-repository.dev.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Maven 1 Repository (legacy)</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/1</url>
        <layout>legacy</layout>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Running that gives:

Error while setting CmdLine  options '[-Xifins, -episode, /home/administrador/JavaApp/wnfe3/wnfe-ejb/target/generated-sources/xjc/META-INF/sun-jaxb.episode]'!

Embedded error: unrecognized parameter -Xifins

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, it looks like the interface injection plugin is no longer well supported. In fact, I'm having trouble finding the JAR for download.

Thankfully, the [JAXB2 Basics Plugins](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/JAXB2+Basics+Plugins) provides a similar mechanism for adding an interface to the generated JAXB stubs (see the [Inheritance plugin](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Inheritance+plugin)).

The JAXB2 Basics plugin is available in the java.net Maven repository.

Using the Inheritance plugin, your POM will look like:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.6.2</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <extension>true</extension>
        <args>
          <arg>-Xinheritance</arg>
        </args>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
               <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
               <version>0.5.3</version>
           </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    ...
  </plugins>
  ...
</build>
```

The [Inheritance plugin documentation](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Inheritance+plugin) has an example for what your JAXB Bindings would look like. For your convenience, I've reproduced the example below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:inheritance="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance"
    jaxb:version="2.1"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="inheritance">

    <!-- ... -->

    <xs:complexType name="WillBeMadeCloneableType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
                <inheritance:implements>java.lang.Cloneable</inheritance:implements>
            </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <!-- ... -->
    </xs:complexType>
    <!-- ... -->
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure this is the "right" way to solve this but, this is what I did. First, download the Interface Insertion Plugin `xjc-if-ins.jar` from https://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/interface-insertion/xjc-if-ins.jar (couldn't find a jar containing `IfInsertPluginImpl.class` in the java.net maven repository).

Then, install the jar in the local repository:

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons \
                         -DartifactId=xjc-if-ins \
                         -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT \
                         -Dpackaging=jar \
                         -Dfile=xjc-if-ins.jar
```

Finally, add the jar as a dependency of the `maven-jaxb2-plugin` in the plugin section:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.6.2</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <extension>true</extension>
        <args>
          <arg>-Xifins</arg>
        </args>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>basic</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.1.5</version>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </configuration>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>xjc-if-ins</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </plugin>
    ...
  </plugins>
  ...
</build>
```

As I said, this is maybe not the cleanest way to configure the jaxb2 plugin to use the Interface Insertion Plugin but, with this setup, the `generate` goal doesn't complain about the `-Xifins` extension.

Comment: Seems like there is really no way to do so without adding the jar in the local repository, I filled a issue for this, thanks

Comment: I agree, we shouldn't have to do this manual stuff and this jar should 1. be available in the java.net repository 2. should be added to the plugin dependencies. Oh, don't forget to accept this answer :)

Comment: I should have said has anyone. I can't figure out where to put that dependency to get it passed through from wsimport to jaxb.

Comment: @Sionide21 You should open an new question, the commenting system is not appropriate to answer this.