# maven jaxb2 plugin - can I avoid jwsdp dependencies

Tags: maven-2, jaxb, jaxb2, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I have a maven build which auto-generates a set JAXB java source files. The basic config is

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <includeSchemas>
            <includeSchema>*.xsd</includeSchema>
        </includeSchemas>
        <excludeSchemas>
            <excludeSchema>test*.xsd</excludeSchema>
        </excludeSchemas>
        <includeBindings>
            <includeBinding>*.xjb</includeBinding>
        </includeBindings>
        <strict>false</strict>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <debug>true</debug>
        <extension>true</extension>
        <!-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999163/how-to-use-jaxb-commons-plugins-from-maven -->
        <args>
            <arg>-Xinheritance</arg>
        </args>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

If i run 'maven clean package' the source files are correctly generated but process goes onto to try and downloaded these jars. I realise I can manually install the required jars from the instructions outlined on the [Maven JAXB Plug-in](http://maven-plugins.sourceforge.net/maven-jaxb-plugin/) page, but I'm wondering is there an alternative way to avoid the sun web service jar dependencies. Should i use different versions for the JAXP or maven plugins?.

```
Downloading: http://host/archiva/repository/internal/jwsdp/jaxb-api/jwsdp.1.5/jaxb-api-jwsdp.1.5.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'jwsdp:jaxb-api:pom:jwsdp.1.5' in repository central (http://host/archiva/repository/internal)
Downloading: http://host/archiva/repository/internal/jwsdp/jaxb-api/jwsdp.1.5/jaxb-api-jwsdp.1.5.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'jwsdp:jaxb-api:pom:jwsdp.1.5' in repository java.net (http://host/archiva/repository/internal)
Downloading: http://host/archiva/repository/internal/jwsdp/jaxb-api/jwsdp.1.5/jaxb-api-jwsdp.1.5.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'jwsdp:jaxb-api:pom:jwsdp.1.5' in repository java.net2 (http://host/archiva/repository/internal)
Downloading: http://host/archiva/repository/internal/jwsdp/jaxb-impl/jwsdp.1.5/jaxb-impl-jwsdp.1.5.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'jwsdp:jaxb-impl:pom:jwsdp.1.5' in repository central (http://host/archiva/repository/internal)
Downloading: http://host/archiva/repository/internal/jwsdp/jaxb-impl/jwsdp.1.5/jaxb-impl-jwsdp.1.5.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'jwsdp:jaxb-impl:pom:jwsdp.1.5' in repository java.net (http://host/archiva/repository/internal)
Downloading: http://host/archiva/repository/internal/jwsdp/jaxb-impl/jwsdp.1.5/jaxb-impl-jwsdp.1.5.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'jwsdp:jaxb-impl:pom:jwsdp.1.5' in repository java.net2 (http://host/archiva/repository/internal)
Downloading: http://host/archiva/repository/internal/jwsdp/jaxb-xjc/jwsdp.1.5/jaxb-xjc-jwsdp.1.5.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'jwsdp:jaxb-xjc:pom:jwsdp.1.5' in repository central (http://host/archiva/repository/internal)
Downloading: http://host/archiva/repository/internal/jwsdp/jaxb-xjc/jwsdp.1.5/jaxb-xjc-jwsdp.1.5.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'jwsdp:jaxb-xjc:pom:jwsdp.1.5' in repository java.net (http://host/archiva/repository/internal)
Downloading: http://host/archiva/repository/internal/jwsdp/jaxb-xjc/jwsdp.1.5/jaxb-xjc-jwsdp.1.5.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'jwsdp:jaxb-xjc:pom:jwsdp.1.5' in repository java.net2 (http://host/archiva/repository/internal)
Downloading: http://host/archiva/repository/internal/jwsdp/jaxb-libs/jwsdp.1.5/jaxb-libs-jwsdp.1.5.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'jwsdp:jaxb-libs:pom:jwsdp.1.5' in repository central (http://host/archiva/repository/internal)
Downloading: http://host/archiva/repository/internal/jwsdp/jaxb-libs/jwsdp.1.5/jaxb-libs-jwsdp.1.5.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'jwsdp:jaxb-libs:pom:jwsdp.1.5' in repository java.net (http://host/archiva/repository/internal)
Downloading: http://host/archiva/repository/internal/jwsdp/jaxb-libs/jwsdp.1.5/jaxb-libs-jwsdp.1.5.pom
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand where do you get these `jwsdp:jaxb-libs` dependencies from. How do you come to the idea that you need them? Maybe one of these [sample projects](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/Sample+projects) may be helpful to get you started. Your projects noramlly have

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${jaxb.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

as dependency. If you're using JAXB2 Basics then you'll also need:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

You normally don't need jwsdp as dependency. But maybe I'm missing something.

Next, this plugin: http://maven-plugins.sourceforge.net/maven-jaxb-plugin/ does not have anything to do with `maven-jaxb2-plugin` you are using.

Finally, I recommend adding JAXB plugins as `configuration/plugins`, not as dependencies. See [this guide](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/User+Guide).

Comment: Thanks for that. The maven command 'clean compile' seems to drag jwsdp in as a dependency after the generation phase has correctly executed. I don't explicity include jwsdp in my pom.xml , i'll have to check the classpath that runs the mvn process to see if there is some issue there.